# How to add NSBezierPath to CALayer in Swift for Mac OS?

Tags: swift, macos, nsbezierpath

I am coding in Swift. And I am writing a Mac OS app. I have created an NSBezierPath, now I want to add it my layer (CALayer)? How do you do that?

```
        let myShape = NSBezierPath()
        myShape.appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter(centrePoint, radius: 150, startAngle: CGFloat(270.0 + CGFloat(testTasksArr.indexOf(task)! + 1)), endAngle: CGFloat(270.0 + CGFloat(testTasksArr.indexOf(task)! + 1) + CGFloat(360/testTasksArr.count)), clockwise: true)
        myButtonLayer.path = myShape
```

The last line doesn't work, as `value of type CALayer has no member path`

Comment: As error state you are using `CALayer` instead of `CAShapeLayer` which has path property

Comment: Oh! I see! That was so obvious! Thanks.